# How to return an array from constructor and successfully chain the object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, constructor

I've been going through the jQuery code and I have seen a few links that have this question. I am asking it again because I did not really understand any of them so please do not mark this question as duplicate. I've gone through the following stackoverflow links:

[How can jQuery return an array and still have it to be a jQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391520/how-can-jquery-return-an-array-and-still-have-it-be-a-jquery-object)

[How does jQuery chaining work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475336/how-does-jquery-chaining-work)

[How does jQuery return an array of the selected objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706106/how-does-jquery-return-an-array-of-the-selected-elements)

Gone through all of those links and I do not get how it works. All I ask is a very simple example of returning an array from a constructor object and still chaining it. I have tried the following code:

```
(function(window, document, undefined)
{
    var lhd = function(selector)
    {
        return new Lhd(selector);
    }

    function Lhd(selector)
    {
        var elem = document.querySelectorAll(selector),
            elems = {};

        return this.makeArray(elems, elem);
    }

    Lhd.prototype = {
        makeArray: function(arr, result)
        {
            var ret = result || [];

            Array.prototype.push.apply(ret, arr);

            return ret;
        },

        click: function()
        {
            console.log('click');

            return this;
        }
    };

    window.lhd = lhd;
})(window, document);
```

I'm able to return an array but unable to chain it.

Comment: you shouldn't return from a constructor.

Comment: `makeArray` returns not `this` but something else. How are you going to chain it?

Comment: the makeArray is returning the same as the jQuery code returns @zerkms

Comment: @DanielA.White, please elaborate more. How should I go about to chain it?

Comment: @Hawk if it is returning the same as jquery then it should work the same as jquery. If it works - why do you ask the question?

Comment: `How should I go about to chain it?` --- chaining is not a magic (and I'm not even sure why people have thought of a special "chaining" term for that), but just returning *some* instance that has the next called method defined.

Comment: From the answer to the first question you've linked: "*jQuery objects are **array-like**, so look and behave a lot like arrays, but are in fact just **custom objects***". Did you understand what this means? There are no arrays.

Comment: `jQuery.makeArray` is **not** chainable, it returns JavaScript `Array`, which is different to `jQuery object`.

Comment: @Bergi, yes, I know what they mean by array-like objects

Comment: At this point, a small piece of code would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm able to return an array

You must not return an array, you must make the new instance (`this`) become array-like.

```
function lhd(selector) {
    return new Lhd(selector);
}

function Lhd(selector) {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

    this.length = 0; // initialise a length
    Array.prototype.push.apply(this, elems); // push onto the instance

    // don't `return` anything - it's a constructor
}

Lhd.prototype.click = function() {
    console.log('click');
    return this;
};
```

You can use it now like `lhd('a').click().click()`.

Comment: thanks a lot, I was frying my mind for the past 2 days. :)